# Can't access "computer" folder from Terminal in Ubuntu VM running in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, root, virtualization

I'm running an Ubuntu 64-bit Ubuntu 14 VM using VirtualBox on Windows 8.1. I wish to access the `computer` folder from Terminal, but I currently can only access it from the file browser GUI.

I'm very new to Linux (about a day), so the solution may be something basic I do not know about yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you open a terminal, the default directory is `/home/USER`. To access the "computer", basically the address is only `/`.

So you can easily, use two methods:

```
cd /
```

or

```
cd ../..
```

(when you type `cd ..` it means you go back a directory (making it to `/home` and then, twice, gets you to `/`)

edit: You can always type `pwd` to know the current directory.